# Upload a file from a local directory using Angular 1.6.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-http

I am building an application using angular 1.6.2.  I have an image upload button in one of my partials.  I'm developing the site and running the server on my local laptop.  All I need to do is upload these images into an images folder in my project locally.   I don't need to do anything fancy.  Am I able to get away with only using HTML5 or do I have to use JavaScript or jQuery?  If I do need js or jq, what would the code look like?

Here is my partial:

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <label>Please Upload your Images</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inputFile" multiple>
</div>
```

Comment: You need something on the server side that takes the file and saves it to the disk

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data to the server to save it.

You can use the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to make a POST request to an endpoint provided by your backend service.

**You cannot save the file on your server without a backend service to handle the request from the front end.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response cnorthfield!

Answer (score 0):

I use a directive that sets the scope variable on the `change` event.

```
<input type=file my-files="files" /><br>
```

**`my-files` Directive**

```
app.directive("myFiles", function($parse) {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on("change", function (e) {
      scope.$eval(attrs.myFiles + "=$files", {$files: e.target.files});
      scope.$apply();
    });
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/CqIixHWefjYmDfmJPbNF?p=preview).

---

### How to POST a File Using the $http Service

When doing a POST of a file, it is important to set the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to `undefined`.

```
var config = { headers: {
               "Content-Type": undefined,
              }
           };

$http.post(url, vm.files[0], config)
  .then(function(response) {
    vm.result = "SUCCESS";
}).catch(function(response) {
    vm.result = "ERROR "+response.status;
});
```

By default the AngularJS framework uses content type `application/json`. By setting `Content-Type: undefined`, the AngularJS framework omits the content type header allowing the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to set the content type.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR Send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

---

### To Download Locally

Use an `<a>` tag with a `download` attribute:

```
<a download="{{files[0].name}}" xd-href="data">
  <button>Download data</button>
</a>
```

The `xd-href` Directive:

```
app.directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       newVal && elem.attr("href", newVal);
     });
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/CqIixHWefjYmDfmJPbNF?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response!  How would I tell my code to save the images directly into a local folder if the local folder is /project/img?

Comment: When downloading, browsers prompt user with a dialog that can be accepted or cancelled. There are security issues with downloading directly. Users don't want evil websites downloading files without their knowledge. For more information, see [MDN HTML Reference - `<a>` Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: That's true, but technically I'm uploading through the site and saving the images to my local /project/img/ directory.  My laptop is behaving like the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys!  This project is for a school assignment.  Even though I may not have permission to use another language, I may wind up writing this in Python: [Creation of a simple HTML file upload page using Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425365/creation-of-a-simple-html-file-upload-page)
.