# Get actual filepath on localhost javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, file-io

I have a frontend designed in html, css and Javascript so I need the user to select the filepath of an excel sheet and pass it onto Python from Javascript. But when I collect the file path through browse the Javascript passes the value as `/fakepath/Excel.xlsx`. This runs locally and doesn't require internet so there is no security issues involved. I search a few posts and it all says it is not possible due to security issues.

What can I do to get the full file path. SO that my python script could take it as an input and work on it?

Comment: There is no perfect solution for this due to security issues as the browser doesn't have access to the path.

However, there are "solutions" that can accomplish something similar:

Have a drop down that lists the files in a directory since its ran locally. That way you can pass along the file path.

Or another option is not worry about the original file at all. Simply have a file input that submits a copy of the file via a file upload to your python script, then work with the copy that was submitted.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the copy file part as an answer? Currently the button file takes multiple files. So before I knew that it makes a fakepath. I thought to pass the list of files to python. @imvain2 please post an answer with multiple excel files.

Comment: This question/answer specifically addresses the uploading to python. You would just need to modify for your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425365/creation-of-a-simple-html-file-upload-page